# Not able to input the textfields on iOS simulators through script/keyboard

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, appium

I am trying to run my automation script on iOS simulator which involves taking the input for the textfield(search, login fields). I am now seeing a problem with this where in the textfield has stopped taking inputs from the script and also from the hardware keyboard attached to my laptop.

### Software versions:

iOS simulator : **10.0** |
Xcode : **8.3.2**

### Code used to input text:

webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(field_element, text).perform()

### Things I tried:

Toggling with all these 3 options available on the simulator **Hardware**-->**Keyboard** settings:

- Uses the same layout as MacOS
- Connect Hardware keyboard
- Toggle Software keyboard

None of the above worked for me.